# PopUpWindow dismissal by back press key

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a popUpwindow which contains this properties:

```
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

After mentioning this also there is a dismissal of popUpwindow when clicked outside the popUpWindow. Can anybody tell me what can be done to avoid this.
And also i have a music getting played in popUpwindow but when it plays i am not able to increase or decrease volume for the same. 
I am not able to access media volume controls when there is popUpwindow in focus. I have read that if there is overidden method onKeydown / up then setVolumeControlsStream(AudioManager.Stream_Music) will not work. But i have used keyDown method to handle backpress rest i am returning return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

Please suggest method to overcome this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  @Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Rect dialogBounds = new Rect();
    getWindow().getDecorView().getHitRect(dialogBounds);

    if (!dialogBounds.contains((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY())) {

        return false;
    }else{
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

}
```

May this help you. i used this to avoid dismissal of Dialog when clicked outside the Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Set focusable to **`false`** for popup window. It will avoid dismissal of `popUpwindow` when clicked outside the `popUpWindow`.

```
popupWindow.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: i tried this but while touching outside boundry it changes background screen and popupwindow still is present in front.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this-
put below line end of your class
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (popupWindow != null)
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
```